# Struggling with the counters of examples and exercises in Problem Sets

Tags: counters

I want two counters, section and number of exercise.
I have this example code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\newcounter{header}
\setcounter{header}{1}

\newcommand{\Header}[1]{ 
    \begin{center}
        #1 Practices Set \theheader 
        \setcounter{exercice}{0}  
        \addtocounter{header}{1}
    \end{center}
}

\newtheorem{exercice}{Exercice}[header]

\begin{document}
    \Header{Matrices.}
    \begin{exercice} This is the first Exercise of Set 1 numbered as 2.1. I would like to number it as 1.1
    \end{exercice}
\begin{exercice} This is the second Exercise of Set 1 numbered as 2.2. I would like to number it as 1.2
    \end{exercice}
    \Header{Systems of Linear Equations.}   
    \begin{exercice}
        This is the first Exercise of Set 2  numbered as 3.1. I would like to number it as 2.1
    \end{exercice} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solves your problem and even makes it possible to refer to headers

```
\newcounter{header}

\newcommand{\Header}[1]{
  \refstepcounter{header}
    \begin{center}
        #1 Practices Set \theheader 
    \end{center}
}
```

First of the start value for `header` should be 0 (it is by default and you can actually remove `\setcounter{header}{0}`). Secondly, you should step up `header` before using it in `\Header` otherwise it makes no sense. Thirdly, as you used `\newtheorem{exercice}{Exercice}[header]`, `exercise` is automatically reset whenever `header` changes, so there is no need to do it manually.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. It works perfectly!!!. You have saved me a lot of time and energy